# My favorite painting is a landscape one

Tags: word-usage

I have seen the usage of "one" in the following kind of sentences:

> My favorite painting is a landscape one.

Here, I want to know whether the word "one " is used appropriately. I think "one" is used as determiner here. I have never seen any other numeral being used in this way.

The complete description is as follows: I like to look at different kinds of paintings. My favorite painting is a landscape one.  I consider that nature is instilled with a lot of beauty and the same is depicted by a painter through his brush and colors in such kinds of pictures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*One* is used there as a noun in its secondary sense:

> 2. A single person or thing; a unit:
>      *This is the one I like best.*
>      *Of her many books, the best ones are the last two.*

[TFDonline.com](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/one)